# Not able to build the Cordova iOS project after updating iOS platform to 4.0.1

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

So for am fine with my ios Cordova application(3.9.2). Today I updated Cordova to 6.0.0 & iOS platform to 4.0.1. But am not able to build because of the compilation errors like

```
- (void) webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    **return [super webViewDidStartLoad:theWebView];**
}
```

[image]

it says, the webViewDidStartLoad is not visible to CDVViewController.

I need these methods for communicating between the native & js side. Please guide me for the above issues please.

Thank you In advance.

Comment: Why do you think it should be visible ?

Comment: I am using  all the **webView** delegates methods in my controller, but after updating Cordova & iOS platform to 4.0.1 then it showing errors. :(

Comment: Updated the error with the screenshot.

Comment: But why do you expect the subclass to know that you are doing something at the superclass, simply because you do ? Is this method declared at the public header of the superclass ? Is the superclass declared to implement the protocols you want to use ?

Comment: yea I know those methods are not declared at public super class, but earlier  those are in. But just want to curious did you ever update a Cordova iOS app? If so how did you resolve the issues which from web view related methods. ?